# Wrong appearence position of context menu

Tags: c#, winforms, mouse, contextmenu

I have a datagridview and need of context menu.
When i right-click on cell (**RED POINT**) - context menu shows..
But in wrong place.
Can't understand why
here is the code:

```
 ContextMenu m = new ContextMenu();
 m.Show(ServersTable, new Point(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y));
```

[image]

That stuff really annoys me!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just translate the point to the grid:

```
m.Show(ServersTable, ServersTable.PointToClient(
    new Point(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y)));
```

Comment: @Greag.Deay, I'm glad I could be of assistance!